# dedekind cut for the square root

Tags: real-analysis

Can somebody give me the hints to solve it ?

1. What is the Dedekind cut $(A, B)$ for  $\sqrt 2$ ?
2. What is the Dedekind cut $(C, D)$ for 
   $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$ ?
3. In $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2 + 1)$, what is the value of $[x^3 + x^2 + x + 1]$? 
   (Just simplify $x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$)
   where $[p]$ means the equivalence class that has $p$ as an element;
   $[p]$ is the set of polynomials $q$ in $\mathbb R[x]$ such that
   $x^2 + 1$ divides $p - q$.
   $\mathbb R[x]$ is the set of polynomials whose coefficients are all real numbers.

Comment: Hint for Q1/Q2: A cut $(P, Q)$ for a real $\alpha$ is such that $P$ has all rationals less than $\alpha$ and $Q$ has all remaining rationals. For Q3, it should have been easy enough once you realize that $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^{2} + 1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ and $[x]$ plays the same role as $i$ plays in $\mathbb{C}$. This should help you out.

Answer (score 5):

1. Try $A=\{x\in\mathbb Q\mid x^2 <2\}\cup  \mathbb Q_{\le 0}$. Why is "$\mathbb Q_{\le 0}$" needed? And what must $B$ look like? Verify that the properties of Dedekind cut are fulfilled!
2. Try $C=\{z\in\mathbb Q\mid \exists x\in\mathbb Q\colon x<z, x^2<2, (z-x)^2<3\}\cup \mathbb Q_{\le 0}$, so $D=\ldots$ Verify that the properties of Dedekind cut are fulfilled! And why is this the cut for $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3$?
3. There is not really a value of $[x^3+x^2+x+1]$, but it is possible to find a representative of minimal degree. Just perform polynomial division to obtani $x^3+x^2+x+1=(x^2+1)(x+1)+0$, i.e. $[x^3+x^2+x+1]=[0]$

Comment: That seems more than "hints." You've certainly left some steps out, but you've given away the hard work.